# Call API via hostname/ip works, but not works via domainname

Tags: docker, dns

I have a application, which hosted via Docker container. I can call this RESTful API successfully via Linux server's hostname or ip (e.g. 172.168.55.88). But I cannot call this RESTful API via domain name (e.g. [www.helloworld.com](http://www.helloworld.com)). Any config I need to do to make it work?

P.S.I have verified, I can call this RESTful API via domain name if this API is hosted via Linux server directly, not from a Docker container. So, DNS config should be working.

I have searched online as much as I can, but I did not find any useful info about this questions.

Comment: Have you mapped the domain name to the IP? The IP you mentioned is the IP of the linux host or the docker container?

Comment: IP I mentioned was linux host. Should I map domain name to docker container ip? How should I get the docker container ip?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Have you ever made it working when you call API via domain name which is hosted via Docker container? If so, could you share more details?

Comment: I did a little experiment. Run an apache docker on a linux with ports mapping `80:80`. Now from the other machine on the same network, when I browse `http://192.168.1.119`  (this is linux host IP) it shows the apache home page. Next I did a hosts file entry on the other machine `192.168.1.119 www.helloworld.com` and then tried to browse `http://www.helloworld.com`. It displayed the apache home page this time too...

Comment: Did another experiment with .NET Core web application running on docker container on linux host. It too worked with both IP and domain name mapped to the IP of the linux host.